# Capture a URL string onclick on a button in a WKWebview having a JS file into an iOS app using Swift

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, uiwebview, wkwebview

I am facing an issue where I want to capture a web URL string that is opened in a WKWebview. The String is opened in another window inside the Webview onclick of a button using `window.open`. Code that initiates the opening of the new window with the URL is -

```
var data = cmp_pv.consentString.getConsentString();
            console.log("Consent writeCookie -----> " + data);
            var fnct = (cmp_pv.conf.hasGlobalScope) ? '_writeGlobalCookie' : '_writeCookie';
            this[fnct](this.vendorCookieName, data, 33696000, '/', cmp_pv.conf.cookieDomain);
            window.open('consent://' + data);
```

I want to get the exact string that is at the end of the URL that has opened on click of the button in the WKWebview.

Answer (score 1):

After you click the button this function will be called,
 you can detect the redirect url through this function:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    decisionHandler(.allow)
      guard let urlString = navigationAction.request.url?.absoluteString.lowercased() else {
          return
      }

      if urlString.contains("what ever you want") {
           // handle the action
      } 
 }
```